# Cannot install Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL2

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, windows-subsystem-for-linux, ubuntu-20.04

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on WSL but I keep getting WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102. Now I've seen other threads addressing this error before and the suggestion is to enable virtualization in the bios and I've already done that. I've enabled SVM as I'm using an AMD chip and I'm still getting this error. I followed the manual installation process for WSL from Microsoft to the letter. My Windows version is 20H2. I have Virtual Machine Platform, Windows Hypervisor Platform and Windows Subsystem for Linux all turned on in the Windows features. I don't know what is going wrong here, I'm well and truly stumped, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In which way are you trying to install it?

Answer (score 0):

What AMD chip? Apart from the other things (BIOS, Virtual Machine Platform, Windows Hypervisor Platform and Windows Subsystem for Linux), to use WSL2 you need a CPU with SLAT (Second Level Address Translation) capability. I found this with a laptop using a Core 2 Duo CPU, (which does not support SLAT, I had to stay with WSL1 on that machine). Check in cmd - run `systeminfo` - at the end of the results there is a section "Hyper-V Requirements" which shows 4 elements. **All 4 of them have to be "Yes".**

[SLAT-Capable CPUs](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1401.hyper-v-list-of-slat-capable-cpus-for-hosts.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

Comment: Please explain what this does and how it solves the problem,  and/or provide a link to a reference that does so. … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.